# prevent full table scan

Tags: oracle, optimization

I have following query:

```
select id,
       c1,
       c2,
       c3 
from tbl t1
join 
(select id 
   from tbl t2
   where upper(replace(c5, ' ', '')) like upper(?)
) j 
on j.id = t1.id
```

`?` is some wildcard parameter string like `%test%`.

`c5` column has index on the function used to access it:

```
create index tbl_c5_idx on tbl(upper(replace(c5, ' ', '')))
```

When I run just inner query it uses `tbl_c5_idx`, however when I run the whole query it turns into full table scan which is much slower.

Are there any way to avoid full table scans? Hints or rewrite join condition. I can not rewrite whole query as inner query is constructed dynamically depending on the input conditions.

Answer (score 1):

A very basic example to test your functionality

```
create table test(id number,value varchar2(200));

insert into test values(1,'gaurav is bad guy');
insert into test values(2,'gaurav is good guy');

SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE UPPER (REPLACE (VALUE, ' ', '')) LIKE UPPER ('%gauravisbad%');
```

before creating index this is doing a `full table scan` for obvious reason ,because no index get created.

```
create index tbl_c5_idx on test(upper(replace(value, ' ', '')));
```

[image: after]

The reason why i am asking you to avoid inner join on the same table because you're using the table twice once to get your records from your filter condition where your index are used and then join on the basis of `id` which is preventing of using index ,because you dont have index on id column,this can be done with a simple filter condition.
Please let me know if you're again finding out the same issue of full table scan ,or you're not getting the same result from this query .

Comment: There are some differences between your and mine queries. You have your values hardcoded and mine uses substitution variables. Despite this query works I can not use it I explained why.

Comment: @mishanesterenko:It work either way ,its just an example to explain how this wil work ,try using a bind variable where you have put a question mark in your query ,then also it is giivng you the same result

Answer (score 1):

- if you're running the subquery only, it doesn't use the id column in the filters the way the parent query does, therefore the index can be used. In the parent query you are using the id as well, which prevents the index from being used. Maybe adding an index on `(id, upper(replace(c5, ' ', '')))` would solve the problem.
- Gaurav Soni is right: you don't need a subquery to achieve your goal.
- always check performances rather than the explain plan. Performances might just be worst with your hint than without. Oracle is **NOT** stupid.

Comment: Actually I need subquery and I explained why. Ok, I write it here: `as inner query is constructed dynamically depending on the input conditions`. About performance: without hint query runs about 40 sec, with hint it runs about 3-4 sec. Execution plan without hint states full table scan, with hint it shows that index range scan is used.

Comment: interesting point about index `(id, upper(replace(c5, ' ', '')))` I will try it

Answer (score 0):

Seems I found solution, or at least a thing that helps.

I used `index` hint, so access is done with `tbl_c5_idx`.

That is how final query looks now:

```
select /*+ index(t1) */ id,
       c1,
       c2,
       c3 
from tbl t1
join 
(select id 
   from tbl t2
   where upper(replace(c5, ' ', '')) like upper(?)
) j 
on j.id = t1.id
```

Comment: ` select id
      , c1
      , c2
      , c3 
   from tbl t1
 where  upper(replace(c5, ' ', '')) like upper(?)`,no need to write inner view

Comment: @GauravSoni, I explained in the question why I need such query. `j` is constructed dynamically depending on input parameters and generally all what it returns is set of some identifiers

Comment: @GauravSoni, your query leads to full table scan